# Multiple selections in UITableViewController control

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am still somewhat of a newbie to iOS development and I have two related questions. In the iOS mail app, one has the ability to go into edit mode, select multiple email messages, and perform some action on them, such as move or delete. Also, when entering edit mode, a toolbar appears at the bottom of the UITableViewController. I want to mimic this functionality but I'm having a hard time finding a resource to use as a guide.

I have added a navigation control to the tableviewcontroller as a container for the Edit button, but I'm not sure if this is the right direction for that. Also, when I add a toolbar control to the form in the storyboard view, it doesn't show up when the UITableViewController loads.

Can somebody point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/table-view-multi-row-edit-mode.html and http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableMultiSelect/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011189-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is very similar to what this tutorial does http://behindtechlines.com/2012/06/enabling-configuring-uitableview-edit-mode/